# AndroidStudio Gradle build ProGuard Duplicate zip entry Error

Tags: android, gradle

What went wrong:

```
Execution failed for task ':proguardRelease'.
java.io.IOException: Can't write [C:\Workspaces\Eclipse\Mixvid\build\intermedi
ates\classes-proguard\release\classes.jar] (Can't read [C:\Workspaces\Eclipse\Mi
xvid\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\Mixvid\meituPic_andcommonlib\unspecified\l
ibs\httpmime-4.2.2.jar(;;;;;;!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF)] (Duplicate zip entry [httpm
ime-4.2.2.jar:org/apache/http/entity/mime/content/ByteArrayBody.class]))
```

I can't delete this duplicate jar because my library needs it, is there any method to solve this?

Comment: If it says `Duplicate zip entry` then you might have multiple files with same name. Find it and delete one.

Comment: Same probleme here. How did you solved it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use gradle `packageOptions` to exclude a class that has a duplicate.

```
android {

    ...

    packagingOptions {
        exclude  'org/apache/http/entity/mime/content/ByteArrayBody.class'
    }

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue today, and found that I have two different versions of one same library:

[image]

[image]

Just remove one then solved issue.

Comment: I've having trouble remove one of these classes. can you please throw some more info about how to remove it?

Comment: @XcodeNOOB Under `app/libs/` folder , just delete jar file.